# What should be the Type of parameter "data" for constructor of a Class in Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, oop

This is my code:

```
export class People {
    name: string;
    age: number;
    constructor(data: any) {
        this.name = data.name;
        this.age = data.age;
    }
}
```

I keep getting error for using any. What should be the type of `data` so that I won't get any error?

I know I can also do:

```
export class People {
    name: string;
    age: number;
    constructor(name: string, age: number) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }
}
```

But I want this model to be used by any JSON say suppose a JSON fetched from server so that I can do:

```
const data = await fetchData();
const person = new Person(data)
```

What changes should I do to keep using the model for any object and also remove all the typescript errors?

I tried changing the type to : `object` , but then I get error on `data.name` and `data.age`

Comment: Where do you get the TS error in your code?

Comment: @Charlie I am getting it at "any" for using "any"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you an use interface checkout this [LINK](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html)

and you code will be look like that

```
interface PersonData {
    name: string;
    age: number;
}

export class People {
    name: string;
    age: number;
    constructor(data: PersonData) {
        this.name = data.name;
        this.age = data.age;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to set up something along the lines of:

```js
interface IPeople {
  name: string;
  age: number;
}

export class People {
    name!: string;
    age!: number;

    constructor(props: IPeople) {
        Object.assign(this, props);
    }
}
```

if you want to do the same thing, but slightly more type-safe, you can just de-structure the props

```js
export class People {
    name: string;
    age: number;

    constructor({ name, age }: IPeople) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }
}
```